# Only negative exponents in Sympy expression

Tags: python, sympy

In sympy I make expressions with a lot of divisions and multiplications,
but the printed results of the expansion varies for identical expressions,
since sympy sometimes uses fracions, `1/x**2`, and sometimes negative exponents, `x**(-2)`.

```
from sympy import symbols
x = symbols('x')

print(expand((3+x)/x/x))
print(expand((1+x)/x/x))
```

output:

```
1/x + 3/x**2
1/x + x**(-2)
```

Given an expression e, how can I force sympy to convert it to negative exponents only?
(and perhaps vice-versa, how to convert to fractions only?)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is by subclassing the `StrPrinter` and apply the modification.

NOTES:

1. Modifying a printer is by no mean an easy task. While your edit appears to be quite straightforward, it might requires a lot more work than the simple code posted here! Please, make sure to dig into the source code of [StrPrinter](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html?highlight=strprinter#sympy.printing.str.StrPrinter), look at the `_print_Mul` and `_print_Pow` method to understand the complexity of their logic. Also, take a look at the respective tests in the source code to fully understand that a simple edit like this, might create problems somewhere else.
2. I'm only going to show you that it works on your two expressions. If it doesn't work in general, it's your work to refine it  Also, I'm only going to show how to print something like `1/x**2` as `x**(-2)`. For anything else, try it yourself :)
3. The following code block works on Jupyter Notebook, so instead of `print(some_expression)` you could just execute `some_expression`. If you are going to call `print(some_expression)`, for some reason the custom-defined printer won't be called.

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing import StrPrinter

class MyStrPrinter(StrPrinter):
    def _print_Mul(self, expr):
        if any(isinstance(a, Pow) and (a.exp < 0) for a in expr.args):
            return "*".join([self._print(a) for a in expr.args])
        return super()._print_Mul(expr)
    def _print_Pow(self, expr, rational=False):
        if isinstance(expr.exp, Integer) and (expr.exp < 0):
            return "%s**(%s)" % (expr.base, expr.exp)
        return super()._print_Pow(expr, rational=rational)

def my_str_printer(expr, **kwargs):
    return MyStrPrinter().doprint(expr)

init_printing(use_latex=False, pretty_print=False, str_printer=my_str_printer)

x = symbols("x")
e1 = expand((3+x)/x/x)
e2 = expand((1+x)/x/x)
```

Then, on different cells:

```py
e1
# out: x**(-1) + 3*x**(-2)
```

```py
e2
# out: x**(-1) + x**(-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the printers already know how to print exponents, if you modify the expression to use Symbol instead of Rational for the exponents, then it will print it as you desire. The following is a hack to do this so the printer prints the expression properly:

```py
exp_hack = lambda e: e.replace(
    lambda x: x.is_Pow and x.exp.is_Rational and x.exp<0,
    lambda x: x.base**Symbol(str(x.exp)))
>>> exp_hack((1 + x)/x**2)
x**-2*(x + 1)
>>> exp_hack(expand((1 + x)/x**2))
x**-1 + x**-2
>>> exp_hack(1/sqrt(x))
x**-1/2
```